# Desktop.getDesktop.open() doesn't exit JVM after the call

Tags: java-8, jvm, ubuntu-18.04

I am opening a directory in Ubuntu 18.04 using Java 8 with the following code

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("\usr\local\share\mydir"));
```

It opens the directory but the program doesnt terminate unless I close mydir. Is this expected behaviour ? Can we terminate the program after the call to open() ?

Ive tried `System.exit(0)` right after the statment but it doesnt work.

I'm running the program from Eclipse .

Comment: Did you try `browseFileDirectory` instead of `open`?

Comment: There is no api like Desktop.getDesktop().browseFileDirectory(), I tried with the browse(file.toURI) but it said the BROWSE action is not supported on the current platform.

Comment: `browseFileDirectory` is Java 9. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: On Windows, it does not block the caller. Did you check whether it blocks the entire JVM or just the thread, i.e. what happens when you use `CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { try { Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(…));
            } catch (IOException ex) {} });   Thread.sleep(2000);   System.exit(0);`?

Comment: Same behavior observed, the program didn't terminate. However, I made a runnable jar and executed it from the terminal and it worked just fine, the java process exited right after opening the directory !